# How to get the inverse of a Matrix3 in three.js?

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, matrix-inverse

The three.js documentation states that [Matrix3](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Matrix3)
has a `.getInverse` function.

But it takes a `Matrix4` as the its first parameter.

So I tried it the naive way in r71:

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix3();
console.log('Initial:', m.elements);
m.set(10,8,3,15,7,2,10,6,1);
console.log('Set    :', m.elements);
console.log('Inverse:', m.getInverse(m).elements);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/as8g61nb/5/ (tested only in Chrome)

But this gives me:

```
Initial: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]                   // OK
Set    : [10, 15, 10, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1]                // Arbitrary numbers
Inverse: [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN] // Not what I expected
```

Wolfram Alpha returns a valid 3x3 Matrix.

Input: `Inverse[{{10, 15, 10}, {8, 7, 6}, {3, 2, 1}}]`

Output: `{{-1/10, 1/10, 2/5}, {1/5, -2/5, 2/5}, {-1/10, 1/2, -1}}`

I've looked into the three.js source code to check what it does in `.getInverse`  but this confuses me even more.

As said before it wants a `Matrix4` as its first parameter and thus accesses `elements[10]` and `elements[11]` which wont work on a Matrix3 and therefore may result in the `NaN` Elements array.

So am I supposed to create a `Matrix4` out of my `Matrix3` then Invert it and convert it back to get my Inverse `Matrix3` ? Or am I missing out on something obvious here ?

Comment: as per the documentation of `Matrix3.getInverse()` found at http://code.google.com/p/webgl-mjs/ (this is where the code was taken from) the function computes the inverse of the given Matrix4, but calculates only the top left 3x3 values of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

three.js is `Matrix4`-based, and hence does not have a method to invert a `Matrix3` directly.

One solution is to use `Matrix4` in your code everywhere.

The other solution is to populate a `Matrix4` from your `Matrix3`, and then call `getInverse()`.

```
var m3 = new THREE.Matrix3();

m3.set( 10,8,3, 15,7,2, 10,6,1 ); // column1, column2, column3

console.log( 'Set    :', m3.elements );

var m4 = new THREE.Matrix4();

m4.set( 10,8,3,0, 15,7,2,0, 10,6,1,0, 0,0,0,1 );

console.log( 'Inverse:', m3.getInverse(m4).elements );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Ok so as I suggested I have to go the way around from 3x3 to 4x4 and then get back to 3x3.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this question, now one can use `Matrix3.invert()` directly.

Example:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

let eye = new THREE.Matrix3().identity();
let inv = eye.invert();
```

It is specified in the [official three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix3.invert).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).